# Parseval's theorem to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle x,x_k\rangle|^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{x_k\}$ be a collection of vectors in a Hilbert space. We take any $x\in H$. The symbol $\langle .,.\rangle$ denote the inner product. The question is as follows. I have to apply the [Parseval's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem) to

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle x,x_k\rangle|^2$$

to obtain a relationship with the Fourier transforms. How should I proceed? What is the result?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: the relationship you seek is $\|f\|_2^2 = \sum_k |\widehat{f}(k)|^2 = \|\widehat{f}\|_2^2$.

Comment: What is $\widehat{f}$? A Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we shall assume that the basis are orthonormal, i.e. $$\left\langle {{x_i},{x_j}} \right\rangle  = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}1,i = j\\0,i \ne j\end{array} \right.$$ now, merely expanding the arbitrary vector in terms of these basis yields $$x = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {\left\langle {x,{x_i}} \right\rangle {x_i}}$$ Now, the "energy" of the vector (it's 2-norm) could be calculated as$$\left\langle {x,x} \right\rangle  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\left\langle {x,{x_j}} \right\rangle \left\langle {x,{x_i}} \right\rangle \left\langle {{x_i},{x_j}} \right\rangle } }  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {{{\left| {\left\langle {x,{x_i}} \right\rangle } \right|}^2}}$$which is probably your desired result. In text, the result is that the 2-norm of the vector (it's length) is the sum of square of it's expansion coefficient (which is quite obvious in Euclidean geometry).

Comment: Thanks, but I desidered a result with Fourier transforms, for example, as for the integrals: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |X(f)|^2 df=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x(t)|^2 dt$.

Comment: @Mark The L.H.S. the equation in your comment is the R.H.S. of the equation in my answer in the limit of infinite non countable basis (so the summation has been transformed to an integral - see the derivation of Fourier transform from Fourier series to gain insight). Also, the R.H.S. of the equation in your comment is obviously the L.H.S. of the equation in my answer.